# Unable to install Pycharm with Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: software-installation, pycharm

I am a newbie with little experience in Ubuntu. I am using ASUS UX32VD with Ubuntu 18.04 installed.
I have been trying to install Pycharm with the following command.

```
sudo snap install pycharm-community --classic
```

but I received the following error message from terminal:

```
error: cannot perform the following tasks: - Download snap "pycharm-community" (64) from channel "stable" 
(Get https://api.snapcraft.io/api/v1/snaps/download/Qo9GiW9eyzgN1tXmWpQ9gdstdFsj4K7E_64.snap: EOF)
```

I sometimes receive this error when I download other files via terminal as well. I have not been able to find a solution.

Moreover, the only variable option for me to download any files is to use terminal.
As I have never been able to download files more than a couple mbps with my browsers, I tried both Firefox and Chrome. All downloads would results in download failure.
I notice that my WIFI drops quite frequently. The WIFI icon on the top right handed side of my screen often turns to a question mark. But I still manage to use internet without problem except for downloading files.

Would this issue simply be caused by internet disconnection? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, this is an Internet problem. It is a 230Mb file, which will take some time to download; your connection is not stable enough and the download needs to be restarted often, ending in a fail.

Comment: Thank you. I let my notebook connected to my phone's network and I downloaded successfully. Not sure why a 24mbps internet is more stable than 500gbps....

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem by following Jos's advice.

I let my notebook connected to my phone's network and I downloaded successfully. Not sure why a 24mbps internet is more stable than 500gbps....
Question closed.